# google oAuth redirect_uri in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, firebase, google-authentication

How to pass paramaters to firebase google auth using redirect. I need to pass a customparameter redirect_uri but I am unable to do it. The snippet goes here..

```
var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
       provider.setCustomParameters({
           'redirect_uri': 'http://localhost:3002/auth-login'
        });

      //then i call the redirect function

        firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

presently unsupported in firebase

Answer (score 0):

According to present documentation for `setCustomParameters`:

> Reserved required OAuth 2.0 parameters such as 'client_id', 'redirect_uri',
>    * 'scope', 'response_type' and 'state' are not allowed and will be ignored.